# mysql_real_escape_string($username) then storing as cookie and used to verify login

Tags: php

So i have a page where i have stored the users username as a cookie and use it for different things. However i have hit a wall. If the username contains anything that is / when using `escape_string` things act up. I was able to get the username to be `echo`'ed correctly on one page however on another page i am not able to get it to come up properly. If i just echo the cookie on that page straight up i get / (the username im using is "" just to test). My server seems to auto escape variables sometimes so i am not 100% sure when it auto applies slashes and when it doesn't, as when i send out variables using php (sending out email with variable) they are escaped and when i save them to the database (sending variable to mysql) they are not slashed? So here is my code for everything i think might help, keep in mind the username in this case is "".

Registering the username:

```
 $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
```

Setting up the cookie:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username']);
$user = stripslashes($username);
setcookie('username', $user, time()+3600*24);
```

Working page:

```
  if(isset($_COOKIE['username']))
   { 
  $login = '<a id="popup_link_3" class="popup_link menu"><span>' . stripslashes($_COOKIE['username']) . '</span></a>'; }
else{ 
 $login = '<a  id="popup_link_2" class="popup_link menu"><span>Login</span></a>';
 }
```

here is where the username is echoed on the working page and i see "":

```
 <? echo $content1 ?>
 <li> <? echo $login ?></li>
 <? echo $content2 ?>
```

Non working page:

```
 $username = $_COOKIE["username"];
```

what i see when i echo `$username` is `/` and when i `stripslashes` i see nothing.

cookie value when viewed through firefox after being set:`%22%22`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using mysql_real_escape_string() for this? The function is intended to make a string safe to insert into a MySQL database query string. it is not, and never has been, intended to be used for usage in a cookie. As long as you're using `setcookie()`, PHP will take care of escaping any data going into the cookie.

Comment: well i use the function to add slashes to the variable im using to compair to whats in the database. then im setting an non-slashed version to the cookie

Comment: There shouldn't be any escapes in the database field. When you escape something to insertion, the escapes are removed by the SQL parser as the data goes into the table. Sending `INSERT INTO x (y) VALUES ("a\b")` will store "ab", not "a\b".

Comment: in my database the values are stored with the /'s

Comment: Then you're double-escaping, and possibly your PHP has magic_quotes-gpc enabled.

Comment: it does have magic quotes on, however if i send "" to mysql database without escaping it saves as ""  however when i send an email with a variable with "" it sends /"/"

Comment: magic quotes are one of the single greatest stupidities in PHP. They should be turned off at all times.

Answer (score 0):

Try an `echo get_magic_quotes_gpc();`. If it echoes `1`, you have magic quotes on, and you should disable that feature in php.ini ([instructions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)).

Comment: well it is turned on, and im looking into figuring out how to turn that off, however i dont think thats my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you not store the users username in the cookie but instead use some form of a session ID, this will make it more secure, then you just use that session ID to fetch the users information from the database, if you are using a database to store the users information.

Comment: i have a hash md5 cookie that is randomly generated when logging in, stored in the database and as another cookie and that is checked as well each time a user wants data from the database.